# Using Laravel's File::makeDirectory to create a folder in the public directory

Tags: directory, laravel-8

I have the following code in my controller - I am trying to create a directory structure to save files into:

```
use File;

...

$path = public_path().'/shared/uploads/images/brands/400';

if (!File::exists($path)) {
    File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0755, true, true);
}
```

When I run the controller I get the following error:

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path (/home/tony/Git/website/public/shared/uploads/images/brands/800/17.png) in file /home/tony/Git/website/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php on line 150
```

Looking in my `public` directory I can see no directory structure has been created.

Looking at other examples of this code doing similar/same thing I can't see any difference with my code except that I am creating the directories in the public folder.

As always, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This was a permission issue.

On my development machine I simply changed the owner of `/shared` to `www-data:www-data`:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data ./shared/
```

Once I'd done that the controller worked fine, creating the rest of the directory structure.